# Vuex, namepaced module getters not available in root getter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

## Namepaced module getters not available in root getter, vuex.

Hey guys,

I have a getter in my root state, this getters needs to reference an other getter (getFilteredSpecialItems) out of a module (filter). I am aware of the rootGetters. I can reference the filter/getFilteredSpecialItems in the vue components, so that's working so far.

**root state**

```
const getters: {
  getSortedList: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
    ...
      console.log(getters);
    console.log(rootGetters);
    console.log(getters.getFilteredSpecialItems);
    console.log(rootGetters.getFilteredSpecialItems);
    console.log(getters.filter.getFilteredSpecialItems);
    console.log(rootGetters.filter.getFilteredSpecialItems);
    ...
    }
}
```

**filter module**

```
const state: {
  namespaced: true
  ...
}

const getters: {
  getFilteredSpecialItems: (state, getters, rootState) => {
    ....
  }
}
```

**folder structure**

```
store
| index.js
| getters.js
| mutations.js
| actions.js
| state.js
| filter (dir)
| \
| | index.js
| | getters.js
| | mutations.js
| | actions.js
| | state.js
```

Both, the getters and rootGetters have registered the filter module (first and second `console.log`):

**getters**
[image: getters]

**rootGetters**
[image: rootGetters]

the 3. and 4. `console.log` are `undefined`, the 5. and 6. throw an error, because `getters.filter` and `rootGetters.filter` are `undefined`, so they don't have any properties.

**How can I get the `getFilteredSpecialItems` inside the root `getSortedList` getter?**

I appreciate any kind of help or advise. Pre-Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access namespaced getters like this:

```
rootGetters['filter/getFilteredSpecialItems']
```

not like this (unlike state):

```
rootGetters.filter.getFilteredSpecialItems
```

From another getter within the same module, you should be able to do this

```
getters.getFilteredSpecialItems
```

If it returns `undefined` then perhaps your getter is returning `undefined`? Confirm that it is actually being called, keeping in mind that its last return value may be cached if no observable data within the getter function has changed since the last call.